# Groupby id and create column boolean column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of transactions:

```
  id |   type |    date
  453| online | 08-12-19
  453| instore| 08-12-19
  453| return | 10-5-19
```

There are 4 possible types: online, instore, return, other. I want to create boolean columns where I see if for each unique customer if they ever had a given transaction type.

I tried the following code but it was not giving me what I wanted.

```
transactions.groupby('id')['type'].transform(lambda x: x == 'online') == 'online'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with aggregate `max` for indicaro columns per groups and last add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for custom order and add possible misisng types filled by `0`:

```
t = ['online', 'instore', 'return', 'other']
df = pd.get_dummies(df['type']).groupby(df['id']).max().reindex(t, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
     online  instore  return  other
id                                 
453       1        1       1      0
```

Another idea with `join` per groups and [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
t = ['online', 'instore', 'return', 'other']
df.groupby('id')['type'].agg('|'.join).str.get_dummies().reindex(t, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Can you think of some aggregation so it can be done with pivot_table?

Comment: @yatu - maybe size with `clip(upper=1)` combination

Comment: Yes, thought about it. tried `first` but it doesn't work here

Comment: @yatu `df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='type', aggfunc= lambda x: bool(len(x)))` may be

Comment: @yatu - no, I got link for this only